# How to use a Python package command inside a python file

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I would like to use **a commandline tool (jupytext) inside a Python file**. In a console, it works like this, which makes a .ipynb file out of .py

`jupytext --to notebook notebook.py`

But I don't want to do it for every file in a console. How can I execute this, when running a Python file itself (.py) in order to generate .ipynb automatically?

On a side note, I came across subprocess, which works fine with UNIX command in a python file, but I am not sure how to apply it for my case:

```
import subprocess
list_of_files = subprocess.run(['ls', '-la'], capture_output=True, text=True)
print(list_of_files.stdout)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
import glob
import subprocess

for py in glob("*.py"):
    subprocess.run(
        ["jupytext", "--to", "notebook", py]
        check=True)
```

However, [`jupytext` has a Python API](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-library.html) too, so it's better to call that
directly from Python for a more efficient solution, and more control over the process, too.

Comment: Associated question is useful but not exacly answer my question. So, I made an answer below.

Many thanks for @tripleee. You code is not exactly working, but you made a right reference and I made it from there! Only a bit of workaround I found is that this library only works in Juypter notebook (thus it did not work in Python file).

Comment: So, my solution was 

```import glob
import jupytext

for py in glob.glob('*.py'):
    ntbk = jupytext.read(py)
    py2 = py.replace('.py', '.ipynb')
    jupytext.write(ntbk, py2)```